# Change all specific letters in a list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to create a program that takes a series of strings as argument, and then exhanges every specific letter in those strings with another letter.

For example:

```
def changeLetter(["test","iteration","123","train"]
```

I want this function to replace every "t" it can find, with "T", and print that list.
so it would look like this:

```
changeLetter(["test","iteration","123","train"]
["TesT","iTeraTion","123,"Train"]
```

Take note!: I am not allowed to use any built-in functions to accomplish this. I can however use len() and range()

Thanks!

Comment: We're not going to do your homework for you. Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: It will be great to share us what you have, then you can take help more friendly.

Comment: This question is completely useless to pretty much everyone else.

Comment: It's not homework, it's studying for a test. And I dont really have anything to share, seeing as I dont know where to start.

Comment: What do you mean by 'built-in' functions?  The reason I ask is because `str.replace()` is a string method, not part of `__builtins__`.  If that is not allowed, then `list.append()` should not be allowed either.

Comment: I mean I have to create it all from scratch, like I cant for example use str.replace()

Comment: `>>> l = ['test', 'iteration', '123', 'train']
>>> [x.replace('t', 'T') for x in l]
['TesT', 'iTeraTion', '123', 'Train']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def changeLetter(item_list):
    result_list = []
    for word in item_list:
        new_word = ''
        for char in word:
            if char == 't':
                new_word += 'T'
            else:
                new_word += char
        result_list.append(new_word)
    print result_list



changeLetter(["test","iteration","123","train"])
```

You can also use string function `replace` for this:-

```
result_list = [word.replace('t', 'T') for word in word_list]
```

Comment: alternate way is  Assuming l = ['test', 'iteration', '123', 'train']
`>>> [x.replace('t', 'T') for x in l]
['TesT', 'iTeraTion', '123', 'Train']`

Comment: @kvivek True, but in the question he mentioned not to use builtin functions.

Comment: I have not used any builtin functions. `replace` is not the builtin function. It is a string function. Just like `append` in your case is a list function.

Comment: Don't know if that's acceptable. I would update anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this,

```
def changeletter(l):
    m = []
    for i in l:
        s = ""
        for j in i:
            if j == 't':
                j = 'T'
                s += j
            else:
                s += j
        m.append(s)
    print m 
changeletter(["test","iteration","123","train"])
```

Output:

```
['TesT', 'iTeraTion', '123', 'Train']
```